# Java inner class access outer class variable

Tags: java, swing, inner-classes

I have a question about inner class access. I am not experienced in Java, so please bear with me.

Below is the code i wrote:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
  ...
  private String selectedNodeString = NULL;     //outer class variable
  private JPanel createControlPanel() {
    ...
    parseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          ...
          tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new MyTreeSelectionListener());
        }
    });



    class MyTreeSelectionListener implements TreeSelectionListener {
      public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        selectedNodeString =        //compile error, can not resolve type

      }
  }
}
```

Below is an example from "thinking in java" explaining inner class access, where inner class can access outer class variable.

```
interface Selector {
  ...
}

public class Sequence {
  private Object[] items;

  private class SequenceSelector implements Selector {
    ...
    private int i = 0;
    public boolean end() { return i == items.length; }
    public Object current() { return items[i]; }
    public void next() { if(i < items.length) i++; }
  }
}
```

So what is wrong with my code, is it more than 1 layer of inner class, and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: `MyTreeSelectionListener` is not an inner class of `MainFrame` as it's declared out side of the class body.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Any reason why this is posted as comment instead of answer?

Comment: @Pshemo Because the OP should be directed to a tutorial and the question closed ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer OK, fair enough, only problem here is that [there will be no](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86043/186652) [RTFM close reason](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253473/1393766) so this question will most probably stay opened until someone will repost what you already wrote in your comment. But I agree with you :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry guys, it's a typo, MyTreeSelectionListener is indeed inside MainFrame. Just correct it. I am dumb but not that dumb :( btw, short answer via comment is good enough. most of my questions does not expect long answers.

Comment: @user1559625 Your code compiles fine for me, regardless if I put this class in outer class or in method http://pastebin.com/j6Di2wM8 For now I vote to put your question on hold until you post code which we could actually use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Is your class MyTreeSelectionListener  inside the method createControlPanel()
I mean this format is correct there are no typos again

Comment: I can't see why it would give you an error (and it's `null` not `NULL`). Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: completely agree should be working fine this

Comment: Thank you guys for advices. I'll double check if i made other mistakes. I knew before that 1 level of nested inner class has no access problem, i thought there maybe difference with more levels, and if not, i am satisfied and will keep checking my side error.

Comment: Gosh, finally i figure out what's going on. I am using Eclipse, for some reason, if i stop at "selectedNodeString = ", Eclipse just does not seem to recognize the type of selectedNodeString. I have to finish the assignment like selectedNodeString = "a"; before the error highlighting goes away. how stange!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a curly brace after the method createControlpanel.

```
private JPanel createControlPanel() {
...
parseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      ...
      tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new MyTreeSelectionListener());
    }
});
} // missing this one.
```

Comment: Thanks for point it out, unfortunately when i try to paste a short version of my original code here, a "}" is missing. But that's not the rootcause.

Comment: I find out what's going on and comment in the above. Not sure if i should be happy or sad. What a waste of time on me!

Comment: @user1559625 Not a waste of time, you will know what to look for if similar cases come up.